# Raspberry Pi as a RealTime wave plotter

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I need to plot a real time signal, 140 points/sec, like an oscilloscope of sorts that traces 7 waves (20 values/sec each). It comes in as a UDP broadcast, this is the visualizer of the traffic. Ideally, this should "flow" to the side, like the output I currently get from the arduino IDE's serial monitor.

I plan to use Qt, which would give me both the networking AND the plotting. I will have an undecorated full-screen modal window (kiosk mode).  Output is on an HDMI Touchscreen 1920 x 1080 (but I do not need to use the full surface for the plot, some 40% of it will be used by a GUI). I am thinking I could buffer the values and plot them out only 2-3 times/sec.

Problem is: I have a Raspberry Pi 3 for iron. Do you think a R.Pi can make it or am I just wasting my time with something too undersized for the job?.

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3 is more than enough for the job. You should only worry about performance if you plan to plot more than 100 000 points a few times a second.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I would better ask before shelling out the money for the hardware!